# How to create nested column using itextsharp?

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

How can I create a table mentioned below,using iext sharp. Below is my code but I am stuceked. Help me to make such a type table.
My code

```
        var subTable2 = new PdfPTable(new float[] { 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100,100,100 });
        subTable2.TotalWidth = 510f;
        subTable2.LockedWidth = true;
        subTable2.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        subTable2.AddCell(new Phrase("Examination", time51));
        subTable2.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        subTable2.AddCell(new Phrase("Board", time51));
        subTable2.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        subTable2.AddCell(new Phrase("Month and Year of Passing", time51));
        subTable2.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        subTable2.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Mark", time51)));
        PdfPTable nested = new PdfPTable(1);
        nested.AddCell("");
        nested.AddCell("Obtained");
        nested.AddCell("Out of");
        PdfPCell nesthousing = new PdfPCell(nested);
        nesthousing.Padding = 0f;
        subTable2.AddCell(nesthousing);
        subTable2.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        subTable2.AddCell(new Phrase("Percentage", time51));
        subTable2.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        subTable2.AddCell(new Phrase("Calss/Grade", time51));
        doc.Add(subTable2);
```

[image]

Comment: Is it OK if I make you a Java example showing how it's done that you can adapt to C#?

Comment: @Bruno Lowagie,ok I wil try

Comment: @Bruno Lowagie,Can you do it now??

Comment: @Bruno Lowagie,Sorry, U carry on :p :p

Comment: It's done! It took me less than a quarter to create the example, a screen shot and the answer ;-)

Comment: It would be great if you could share the C# version of the example once you've finished porting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at [SimpleTable12](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/tables/SimpleTable12). It creates a table that looks like this: [simple_table12.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/simple_table12.pdf)

[image]

You could still fine-tune the height of the cells by using a padding or by introducing descender/ascender info, but those are details. What matters is: *how to organize the cells?*

I've written this small convenience method:

```
public PdfPCell createCell(String content, int colspan, int rowspan, int border) {
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(content, font));
    cell.setColspan(colspan);
    cell.setRowspan(rowspan);
    cell.setBorder(border);
    cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    return cell;
}
```

You pass some content, a colspan, a rowspan and border info and it creates you the `PdfPCell` you need. This allows us to create code that is easier to read:

```
public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    font = new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 10);
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    document.open();
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(8);
    table.setWidthPercentage(100);
    table.addCell(createCell("Examination", 1, 2, PdfPCell.BOX));
    table.addCell(createCell("Board", 1, 2, PdfPCell.BOX));
    table.addCell(createCell("Month and Year of Passing", 1, 2, PdfPCell.BOX));
    table.addCell(createCell("", 1, 1, PdfPCell.TOP));
    table.addCell(createCell("Marks", 2, 1, PdfPCell.TOP));
    table.addCell(createCell("Percentage", 1, 2, PdfPCell.BOX));
    table.addCell(createCell("Class / Grade", 1, 2, PdfPCell.BOX));
    table.addCell(createCell("", 1, 1, PdfPCell.BOX));
    table.addCell(createCell("Obtained", 1, 1, PdfPCell.BOX));
    table.addCell(createCell("Out of", 1, 1, PdfPCell.BOX));
    table.addCell(createCell("12th / I.B. Diploma", 1, 1, PdfPCell.BOX));
    table.addCell(createCell("", 1, 1, PdfPCell.BOX));
    table.addCell(createCell("", 1, 1, PdfPCell.BOX));
    table.addCell(createCell("Aggregate (all subjects)", 1, 1, PdfPCell.BOX));
    table.addCell(createCell("", 1, 1, PdfPCell.BOX));
    table.addCell(createCell("", 1, 1, PdfPCell.BOX));
    table.addCell(createCell("", 1, 1, PdfPCell.BOX));
    table.addCell(createCell("", 1, 1, PdfPCell.BOX));
    document.add(table);
    document.close();
}
```

As you can see, it's a matter of calculating the correct `colspan` and `rowspan` values, and applying the correct borders.

Comment: ,Let me try ..Thank you

Comment: Could you please provide your valuable inputs here Bruno,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70921938/how-to-achieve-multi-header-in-itext