# How to create a table with multiple headers in iText?

Tags: java, spring-boot, itext

How do I achieve the following:

[image]

Currently I can get till Single Header Table:

[image]

How do I add a column header above a column which will have colspan.

Comment: Can you share your code as a minimal reproducible example along with your output pdf? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 4):

To create a table with multiple headers use Table#addHeaderCell, as in example below:

String fileName = "test.pdf";

```
    PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(destinationFolder + fileName));
    Document doc = new Document(pdfDocument);

    Table table = new Table(10).useAllAvailableWidth();

    table.addHeaderCell(new Cell(1, 5).add(new Paragraph("2019")).setBackgroundColor(DeviceRgb.BLUE).setBold())
            .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
    table.addHeaderCell(new Cell(1, 5).add(new Paragraph("2020")).setBackgroundColor(DeviceRgb.BLUE).setBold())
            .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        table.addHeaderCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Number")).setBackgroundColor(DeviceRgb.BLUE).setBold());
        table.addHeaderCell(
                new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Firstname")).setBackgroundColor(DeviceRgb.BLUE).setBold());
        table.addHeaderCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Lastname")).setBackgroundColor(DeviceRgb.BLUE).setBold());
        table.addHeaderCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("City")).setBackgroundColor(DeviceRgb.BLUE).setBold());
        table.addHeaderCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Age")).setBackgroundColor(DeviceRgb.BLUE).setBold());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 70; i++) {
        table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("One")));
        table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Two")));
        table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Three")));
        table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Four")));
        table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Five")));
    }

    doc.add(table);
    doc.close();
```

The output PDF can be found on image above (not full) [image]

If this doesn't solve your problem, could you please share your code snippet to investigate it and try to help you.